# Mouse Adapter program not working

Tags: java, swing, adapter

```
public class MouseDetailsFrame extends JFrame {

private String details;
    private JLabel statusbar;

    public MouseDetailsFrame(){

        super("MouseFrame");

        statusbar= new JLabel("Click The Mouse");
        add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    addMouseListener(new MouseClickHandler());


    }
    private class MouseClickHandler extends MouseAdapter{


        public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent event){
            int xPos= event.getX();// has no use anywhere, i wonder why that is
            int yPos= event.getY();// same

            details= String.format(" clicked %d times:", event.getClickCount());


                    if (event.isMetaDown())
                        details = String.format(" clicked %d times:"+"with right mouse", event.getClickCount());
                    else if(event.isAltDown())
                        details=String.format(" clicked %d times:"+"with middle mouse", event.getClickCount());
                    else 
                        details =String.format(" clicked %d times:"+ "with left mouse", event.getClickCount());

                    statusbar.setText(details);
        }

    }
}
```

// nothing happens when i run it through the main string. A window just shows up the statusbar doesnt show how many time i click or if i clicked with left or right mouse button. Just give me hint please, i want to do this myself.

Comment: `isMetaDown()` Please educate me -- why check that? And you mention right and left mouse buttons, but I never see where you check for this. Have you gone through the tutorials and the API yet? If not, run don't walk there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add an @Override annotation to your `MouseClicked` method - what do you notice?
   **This** is one of the cases in which `@Override` spares you from grief.
2. Go and check the javadoc for the `mouseClicked` method: do you notice the spelling difference?

Comment: Whoa, chill down, that's nothing. Just keep in mind your mistakes, how to avoid make them in the same way for the future (the `@Override` annotation in this case) and you'll never get bored with the *new, fresh and tasty bugs* you'll create in the future - that's inevitable. Good luck and enjoy,